# MVC 4 - Remove /Home/ from address bar and retain folder name for others

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4 and need to remove /Home/ folder from address bar...

**Eg**:

`http://localhost:61700/Home/AboutUs`

Need to be changed as...

`http://localhost:61700/AboutUs`

I did that by changing the default controller in "**RouteConfig.cs**"

```
public class RouteConfig
{
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
                routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "Default",
                        //url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        url: "{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
        }
}
```

> The above code is working as expected. I do have another folders as
>   brand, admin etc... here I want to show the url as
>   `http://localhost:61700/brand/productInfo` ... But I am getting server
>   error here as `Server Error in '/' Application.`

Can somebody suggest me, where am I doing wrong?

Screenshots here for more info:

[image]

Comment: You need to add a specific route with `url: "AboutUs",` and `defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AboutUs"` (and put it before the default route)

Comment: Hi **@StephenMuecke** Thanks for the answer but I have 160+ views in Home folder, should I need to mention all **ulrs** ?

Comment: If you want to strip the `/Home/`, then yes, you will need a specific route for each one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your current `RouteConfig.cs` configuration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You're telling `Asp.net`, when a request arrives, assume the first parameter as the `action` and the second parameter as the id. Right now you're not telling `Asp.net` to parse any parameter as the `controller`. Because of this it uses the default value (given as the third parameter of the `MapRoute` method) which is in this case `Home`.

In that case when parsing the request `http://localhost:61700/AboutUs` the values end up being:

- controller: `Home` (it uses the default controller)
- action: `AboutUs` (from the first parameter)
- id: `null` (this doesn't matter right now)

When parsing the request `http://localhost:61700/brand/productInfo` the values end up being:

- controller: `Home` (it uses the default controller because you haven't specified where to get the controller name from)
- action: `Brand` (from the first parameter)
- id: `"productInfo"`

The error you're getting is because there isn't a `Brand` action method in `HomeController.cs` with a parameter of type `string` named `id`.

`Asp.net` processes incoming requests by trying to match with the routes configured and it uses the first route that matches.

There are several ways to achieve what you want, which include but are not limited to:

1. Manually mapping every action in your `HomeController.cs` (choosing this method will depend on the amount of actions in your `HomeController`). This would look like:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "AboutUs",
       url: "AboutUs",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AboutUs" }
       );

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "ContactUs",
       url: "ContactUs",
       defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "ContactUs" }
       );

   // etc...

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```

   Note how the default route is the last one, this is important because it is less specific than the others and if put before would match the request and want to look for an `AboutUsController`.
2. You could use route constraints. This would look like:

   ```
   route.MapRoute(
       name: "HomeControllerRoutes",
       url: "{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
       constraints: new { action = "AboutUs|ContactUs|etc..." } //Here you would put all your action methods from home controller that you want to accces as /{action}
   );

   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Default",
       url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```

   If you want to read more about route constraints, I found [this](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints) article that explains that the `constrains` parameter can receive a **regular expression** (I suggest you modify the regular expression above to make it case insensitive) **or** an [**`IRouteConstraint`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

## Update:

I just read your comment about having 160+ actions in your `HomeController` that would make your regular expression in my second suggestion quite long. In that case the other options you have could be:

3. Using a regular expression that rejects all other controller names, but that would violate the open/closed principle ([OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)) and every time you add another controller you would have to add it to the regular expression.
4. Create the regular expression from the metadata of you `HomeController` class. This would look like

   ```
   string.Join("|", typeof(HomeController).GetMethods().Select(info => info.Name))
   ```
5. Or you could take a look at [**`IRouteConstraint`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to see if you could figure out a more elegant solution.

   I have no experience with `IRouteConstraint`

Comment: Hi **@mamodom** ... Thanks for the update. I am going to go with your **option 2** while it is not much complicated though I have many files. **I am upvoting and Accepting your answer** too. Thank you somuch for your time in explaining in detail...

Comment: That's why we're here!

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your route.config / glibal.asax and don't change your default routes. Add following above it.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "About",       
        url: "AboutUs",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "AboutUs" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: **@Suprabhat Biswal** Should I need add above code 160+ times as I have those many files in Home controller?

Comment: @Reddy What kind of files? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Default route will handle normal flow "*http://localhost:61700/brand/productInfo*" for exceptional cases like "*http://localhost:61700/AboutUs*"  or "*http://localhost:61700/Contactus*" etc. you need to write different routes.

Comment: I have 160+ home view files in Home Controller like Reports, user profiles, company info, others etc...

Answer (score 0):

> I have 160+ views in the home controller

You don't mention how many views you have in the other controllers, nor how complicated they need to be.

Rather than keep the default `controller/action` and add routes for every view in home, you can add a route for each controller and then have your default route without a controller path.

While this means you do need a route for every controller, it's better than one for every view.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminRoute", 
    "Admin/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    "BrandRoute", 
    "Brand/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Brand", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    "HomeRoute", 
    "{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultRoute", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

(afaicr you don't need the default route as all your views would be covered by the other 3 routes)

Note the path for 'HomeRoute' doesn't have a controller part.

As long as they are *in this order* any url with /Admin/ or /Brand/ will be picked up first.